# I want to sell a non-marketable hat in TF2. Is there any way to go about it?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

I just crafted a SUPER EPIC NEW HAT!
Unfortunately I just did it for cash as I've pretty much quit TF2.

I wanted to know, how can I get money from this hat?

Comment: Trading questions don't belong here.

Comment: @Keavon When did that happen?

Comment: @Studoku I kinda just assumed it. Do you mean this is appropriate here?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't belong here. They're asking about an in-game item, which I feel is not off-topic at all. Now, if they were advertising their trade here, then I'd say it doesn't belong.

Comment: @Gigazelle Okay, thanks for the info. I have withdrawn my downvote. However, would a question such as "what is the value of my [insert TF2 item here]?" be acceptable?

Comment: Value is subjective and opinion-based, so I'm definitely leaning towards 'no' on that one. The asker would be better off referencing trading sites like backpack.tf to get a ball-park range of value for a given item.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to make money from digital goods.

Comment: Sorry if this has inconvenienced anyone but I rely on this website to answer my questions because the Stack Exchange network is best for answering questions :) I will direct my other questions regarding trading to Steam in future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trade it to other players, provided they pay you however much you'd like to get for it.

Comment: Steam Id is something like want AWP Boom/Redline \_('-')_/ Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Any clarification on downvotes? @Clarinetking asked how to sell a non-marketable item, I answered